# TSQL How to calculate exam result based on values from multiple rows

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I need to calculate the exam result of students based on marks from each subject stored in separate rows. Please see the Marks table below.

[image]

I'm expecting a result as
[image]

The query I tried is coming too lengthy and too many conditions. Please someone help me how to achieve this with a simple TSQL.

Comment: How do you define "Fail" or "Pass" ?

Comment: *"The query I tried is coming too lengthy and too many conditions."* What was that attempt? If you show us what you have, we may well be able to show you how to simplify it.

Comment: Please read [this](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question. Providing sample data where all of the columns are data type `pixel` makes it harder for us to help you. What error did you get when you tried to post your existing "too lengthy" query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have minimum mark criteria for each subject, then check it with a `CASE` expression. And then use another `CASE` expression to check whether the no. pass criteria is matching with the total no.

**Query**

```
declare @minMark as int = 35; -- change accordingly

select [sid],
case when (
    sum(case when [marks] >= @minMark then 1 else 0 end) = count(*)
) then 'Pass' else 'Fail' end as [stat]
from [your_table_name]
group by [sid];
```

Comment: Simple and superb answer, Thanks @Ullas

Answer (score 0):

If "based on marks" means "based on whether some threshold has been reached", the query like that will help you.

Let's say SID passed exams when sum of marks equals or greater than 123

```
select sid, 
       case when sum(marks) < 123 then -- replace 123 with the threshold value
         'Failed'
       else
         'Passed'
       end result
  from test_table
 group by sid
```

[here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=730322c8199915995cbbf4d649ec238e) is the db fiddle to play with

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned **based on marks from each subject.**

Means if any student have lesser marks in any subject then the student will be considered as failed.

```
;with test_table(sid, sub, marks) as (
  select 23, 'English', 35 union all
  select 23, 'Maths', 40 union all
  select 23, 'Science', 20 union all
  select 24, 'English', 60 union all
  select 24, 'Maths', 50 union all
  select 24, 'Science', 66
),
final_result as (
select sid, sub, case when marks < 33 then -1 else 0 end result 
from test_table 
)
select final_result.sid,  case when sum(final_result.result) < 0 then 'Failed' else 'Passed' end FinalResult 
from final_result
group by final_result.sid
```